# jQuery animate finished function

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make a fullscreen section scroll page. I'm already able to prevent the default user scrolling. Now, to replace that I use the following code:

```
var isAutoScrolling = false;
$(window).off('scroll.fullscreen');
$(window).on('scroll.fullscreen', function () {
    if (isAutoScrolling === false) {
        isAutoScrolling = true;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(nextDiv).offset().top
        }, '400', 'linear', function () {
            console.log('animated');
            isAutoScrolling = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Unfortunately the console.log writes 'animated' 2 times per scroll. How is this possible? The code above should at least make a 400ms break between 2 console.logs, right? Anyone catching the error in this?

Comment: Missing `)` of `on()`;

Comment: Can you share a demo to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: @A.Wolff Interesting. You have an upvote from me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Issue comes from *you are* binding event on two elements html, body. Some
>   browser would then fire it twice (some others have ony one of these
>   elements scrollable, so fire it only once).

You can use `promise` interface and relevant method to normalize it across browser.

```
$(window).on('scroll.fullscreen', function () {
    if (isAutoScrolling === false) {
        isAutoScrolling = true;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(nextDiv).offset().top
        }, '400', 'linear').promise().done(function () {
            console.log('animated');
            isAutoScrolling = false;
        });
    }
});
```

<strike>That's said, i guess instead of using a flag, you could use [:animated](https://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) pseudo selector:</strike>

```
$(window).on('scroll.fullscreen', function () {
     $('html, body').filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
         scrollTop: $(nextDiv).offset().top
     }, '400', 'linear').promise().done(function () {
         console.log('animated');
     });
 });
```

(see @Ionică Bizău's comment below)

Comment: Isn't calling `$('html, body').filter(':not(:animated)')` everytime you scroll too bad from performance perspective?

Comment: @IonicăBizău I would say ya, it would be quite consuming, so a flag indeed seems a better approach

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks.